EclipseにTomcatを登録してJavaアプリ開発をしていると、server.xmlが勝手に書き換わる
症状
Eclipseを使ったJavaアプリ開発時に、Tomcatを再起動するタイミングでserver.xmlが自動的に書き換わる。
書き換え後の内容は下記の通り。
書き換えによってpasswordが古いものになってしまい、毎回SQLException（Access denied）になってしまって困っている。
 <Context docBase="C:\pleiades\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\school_library_war" path="/school_library_war" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:school_library_war">
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" maxIdle="30" maxTotal="100" maxWaitMillis="10000" name="jdbc/searchman" password="spass" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_library?serverTimezone=Asia/Tokyo&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" username="suser" validationQuery="SELECT 0"/>
</Context>

環境
OS：Windows 11
統合開発環境：pleiades-2022-06-java-win-64bit_20220619
開発言語：openjdk 17.0.4.1 2022-08-12
サーバー：apache-tomcat-9.0.65
調べたこと
「server.xml 自動」「server.xml 勝手に」「server.xml 書き換わる」で15分ほど検索したが、server.xmlが書き換わるという情報は見つけられなかった。
知りたいこと
server.xmlが勝手に書き換わらないように設定する方法or書き換え内容を制御する方法（新しいpasswordでserver.xmlが自動生成されるようにする方法）があれば知りたいです。

すみません、またしても自己解決しました。
META-INF以下のcontext.xmlにjdbcのパスワードの情報等が載っていたので、それを更新したらserver.xmlの方にも新しいパスワードが反映されるようになりました。
今回は秀丸エディタのGrep検索でEclipseフォルダ配下で「spass」で検索したことで解決策にたどり着きました。
質問を消すことも考えましたが、誰かの役に立つ可能性もなくはないので残しておきます。
質問を投稿すると頭が冴えてくる現象、いったい何なんだ…。
